# Angular 6: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test scrollIntoView() in angular 6 and got this error --> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null`

spec:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BusinessInfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    spyOn(document.getElementById('info-banner'), 'scrollIntoView').and.callThrough(); 
    expect(document.getElementById('info-banner').scrollIntoView).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(document.getElementById('info-banner')).not.toBeDefined();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  document.getElementById('info-banner').scrollIntoView();

}
```

Comment: Can you add the component html.  Info banner is present in this component

Comment: @HitechHitesh I don't have info-banner in my component's html, I'm referring that from a different component with document.getElementById(info-banner)....

Comment: That's why it is not working

Comment: will it be possible to test this particular scenario ?? @HitechHitesh

Comment: Does the code works in running

Comment: Yes and my only concern is because of this all my other tests are failing and I'm not able to figure it out the solution.. @HitechHitesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('info-banner').scrollIntoView();` should go into `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook.

Basically any DOM referencing should go into that hook. When `ngOnInit()` is executed, DOM doesn't exist yet and therefore the error.

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: @Ramana my question would then be do you have the `info-banner` in your component's html? What angular recommends is to use `ViewChild` rather than native js functions.

Comment: I don't have the info-banner in my comment's html.. can you help me with any any references / examples how to use ViewChild to test this scenario ??

Comment: @Ramana If you don't have that element in your component's html, why would you need to reference it? For `ViewChild`, you can have a read of this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild

Comment: A quick example: in your component's html: `<div #infoBanner></div>`; in your ts: `@ViewChild('infoBanner') infoBanner: ElementRef;` and in `ngAfterViewInit()` you have `this.infoBanner.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();`

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the previous answers but none worked for me. I came up with a workaround:

⚠️⚠️ WARNING ⚠️⚠️:
this code is not recommended for enterprise applications.
The problem is that it will not always take less than 50ms for myTarget from @ViewChild to become defined, thus the scrolling might not take place 100% of the time. However as for performance it is not a big problem I think.

That being said, this worked for me in 100% of the cases in my app so far so it is a good workaround for small hobby/school/university projects. In my app the wait always took less than 3ms. You can comment-in the commented-out line in your app to see how long it would take for your component.

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {
      let timesThat1MSWasWaited = 0;
      while (this.myTarget === undefined) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1));
        if (timesThat1MSWasWaited > 50) {
          console.error('FatalException: Waited too long for highlighted song to appear in DOM.');
          return;
        }
        timesThat1MSWasWaited++;
      }
      // console.debug('Needed to wait at least ' + timesThat1MSWasWaited + 'ms for myTarget to appear.');

      this.myTarget.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'center',
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Spec:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BusinessInfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    spyOn(window.document.getElementById('info-banner'), 'scrollIntoView').and.callThrough(); 
    expect(window.document.getElementById('info-banner').scrollIntoView).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(window.document.getElementById('info-banner')).not.toBeDefined();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Angular class

```
ngOnInit() {
  window.document.getElementById('info-banner').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Did you also include "window." to the documents in the tests? document is not in the scope of angular, you have to prepend it with window to be able to use it.

Comment: updated still same issue, TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the angular testing suite, but I recommend you to check first if the window object exists in the test, maybe the suite does not mimic a real browser completely.. Also test the same code in the browser, see if it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
  // Get the reference of the variable 
@ViewChild("myDiv") divView: ElementRef;

   this.divView.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
```

```
<div id="info-banner" #myDiv >Info </div>
```

Look into this link

https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-elementref/

For accessing outside elements check this

[Access DOM element outside of Angular root component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873312/access-dom-element-outside-of-angular-root-component)